# Review Form is not showing on the product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, forms, review

I have added the following configuration code to the config.xml to show the review section on product view but it just showing the heading of the review section and not the actual form there.

```
 <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
   <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
   <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
 </block>
```

What else i need to do to make it work in perfect way,

Answer (score 2):

Please check `review/product/view/list.phtml` file.

And add below code before close div in last line(almost 67 or 68).

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/form')->setTemplate('review/form.phtml')->toHtml()
```

If here, review form in calling already like this:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form')
```

Please comment this code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple code in review.xml file to show reviews and review form under product description

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>review_info</group></action>
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
                <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data_review" template="review/product/view/reviews-in-tab.phtml">
                    <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
                </block>
            </block>              
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in your `review.xml` layout theme file.

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
                <action method="addToParentGroup">
                    <group>detailed_info</group>
                </action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value">
                    <value>Reviews</value>
                </action>
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
                <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data_review" template="review/product/view/reviews-in-tab.phtml">
                    <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```